# Bluetooth headset no sound Ubuntu 22.04 Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, headphones

I've been looking around for couple of days to find out why my bluetooth headset is not working. No luck to find the correct answer.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with all the latest updates on brand new Lenovo T14 Gen 4 AMD laptop with Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765 chipset. So far I do not have problems to connect any other bluetooth device such as mouse or my mobile phone.

Starting from beginning.
After fresh install, when I connect my headphones, I couldn't hear any sound out of it even when they are selected as an sound sink device. After some time, headphones disconnects from the system. Doesn't matter which profile I've been using (A2DC or HSF).

Sometimes when I try to connect my headphones manually, I got an error tht connection failed. Nor info from bluetoothctl output.

Output of syslog:

```
Dec  3 02:39:13 T14GEN4 boltd[838]: probing: started [1000]
Dec  3 02:39:14 T14GEN4 bluetoothd[833]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to 88:C9:E8:DE:59:32: Connection refused (111)
Dec  3 02:39:14 T14GEN4 bluetoothd[833]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 88:C9:E8:DE:59:32: Connection refused (111)
Dec  3 02:39:15 T14GEN4 boltd[838]: probing: timeout, done: [2002267] (2000000)
Dec  3 02:39:16 T14GEN4 bluetoothd[833]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 88:C9:E8:DE:59:32: Connection refused (111)
```

I've try to google all this problems. No luck to find a solution.

As suggested on one of the forum, I've upgraded my system to pipewire set-up. Problem still exist.

Output of *wpctl status* command:

```
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, cookie:3685269842]
 └─ Clients:
        32. pipewire                            [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:1576]
        34. WirePlumber                         [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:1574]
        35. WirePlumber [export]                [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:1574]
        53. xdg-desktop-portal                  [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:1626]
        54. Plasma PA                           [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:1767]
        56. wpctl                               [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:8309]
        58. Firefox                             [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:2867]
        63. Firefox                             [1.0.0, sajon@T14GEN4, pid:2867]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      45. HD-Audio Generic                    [alsa]
 │      46. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [alsa]
 │      59. OPPO Reno6 5G                       [bluez5]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   47. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Speaker + Headphones [vol: 0.74]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      48. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Headphones Stereo Microphone [vol: 1.00]
 │  *   49. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Digital Microphone [vol: 0.74]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
         0. Audio/Sink    bluez_output.88_C9_E8_DE_59_32.a2dp-sink
```

I thought that maybe Bluez is not up to date. Based on the info from [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/install-bluez-latest-version-on-ubuntu/), I've compiled latest version 5.70. That didn't solve the problem either.

uname:

```
Linux T14GEN4 6.5.0-1008-oem #8-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Nov 10 13:08:33 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e8
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e9
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:04.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ef
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1959
64:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15bf (rev dd)
64:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
64:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c7
64:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b9
64:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ba
64:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 63)
64:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
65:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
65:00.1 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1502
66:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
66:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c0
66:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c1
66:00.6 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1669
```

I start to think, that it can be hardware related problem. What do you think? At the moment I do not have a chance to verify my computer hardware with Windows based OS. I've ordered an external USB bluetooth dongle which will arrive after the weekend. Let see.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have T14 Gen 4 AMD. I observe similar problems as you do (I cannot connect my BT headphones properly under Ubuntu 22.04). I can confirm they work well under Windows. Did you have any progress with debugging this?

Comment: Hi, for me problem was hardware related. My headphones didn't work under Win and Ubuntu. Service replaces motherboard of my computer and everything start working as it should be.
If it works correctly under Windows, check if your headset is actually supported under linux.